# Scale collider2d based on half of mobile screen doesn't work after deployed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm changing the scale of boxcollider2d of prefab based on half of screen size of mobile device. When I tried using unity remote its scaling correctly but once deployed on mobile it's not scaling correctly. Below is the code attach to a gameobject:

```
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().offset = new Vector2(0, 0);
float halfofscreen = (Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2.0f) * Screen.width / Screen.height;
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector3(halfofscreen / transform.lossyscale.x , 5f, 0);
```

I don't know what's causing this

Comment: Has `halfofscreen` the correct value?

Comment: Update. The code is working I just mislooked something